# How do I control a variable value from an ExpressionAnimation?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm using the [AnimatedVisualPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.animatedvisualplayer?view=winui-2.4) within the Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace. I want the progress of the animation that is playing back to be available as a double so that I can update the value of progress slider.

The AnimatedVisualPlayer provides a [ProgressObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.animatedvisualplayer.progressobject?view=winui-2.4#Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls_AnimatedVisualPlayer_ProgressObject) which is a [Composition Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionobject?view=winrt-19041) which you are supposed to bind to some property via an [ExpressionAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.expressionanimation?view=winrt-19041). Rather then using this object to drive another animation, I would like to have the animations progress available as a value. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 internal void ProgressObjectToValue(CompositionObject ProgressObject)
    {
        var c = Window.Current.Compositor;

        SpriteVisual targetVisual = c.CreateSpriteVisual();

        ExpressionAnimation exp = c.CreateExpressionAnimation($"comp.Progress");

        exp.SetReferenceParameter("comp", ProgressObject);

        targetVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.X", exp);


        double progressValue = targetVisual.Offset.X;
```

With this, it seems the targetVisuals offset is not bound to the AnimatedVisualPlayer's progress. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

> I want the progress of the animation that is playing back to be available as a double so that I can update the value of progress slider.

Derive from `AnimatedVisualPlayer` TestUI [project](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/pull/1558/files/17d02f6a50a713d15b3dd866ea61de009c63e2f4#diff-bd0f51ec1417b7a8de67dc94acccc816R145), we use the following to get progress value, during the testing, it always return 0 or 1 value.

```
var progressPropertySet = (CompositionPropertySet)Playback_Player.ProgressObject;
progressPropertySet.TryGetScalar("progress", out var value);
var progress = value.ToString();
```

For this scenario, we suggest you use timer to detect animation time, and use it to divide AnimatedVisualPlayer `Duration` property to get progress.